# How celery works when there is one worker and multiple queues?

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to understand how it works when there are multiple queues with a number of tasks in each of these queues. I ran some tests on my local machine, and found that even if there are multiple queues, the worker always takes the tasks in the order in which they were enqueued. The reason why I am using multiple queues is to allow celery worker to pick the tasks from these queues in a round robin fashion.

Please help me understand how it works and what I can do to implement this system.

Thanks in advance :)